# Adding Mixare in androidstudio into my app

Tags: android, integration, augmented-reality

I want to integrate Mixare app into my own app. I downloaded the Mixare source code from http://www.mixare.org/download/ and opened it in my androidstudio. But I cannot run the project after syncing gradle. 
I have searched for how to integrate mixare app into my app using android studio but couldn't find anything, since Mixare's site is not updated and I think the developers of Mixare have stopped working on it. Can someone help me on how to add this augmented reality Mixare into my own app?

Comment: Just wondering if you figured out the answer?

Comment: Nope, the people who worked on Mixare are no longer active, as far as I know.